# MySQL Regular expression search

Tags: php, mysql

Iam struck with a search query in mysql, where i want to show a user's name like John-Chow, if i enter the search string in my textbox as John Chow.

How to do this with mysql regular expression search ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

1. explode the textbox string in words
2. use the following regex :
       `words1.*?words2`...`.*?wordsN`

Comment: Fine, i did as you said. First i exploded the text box string with space, and then imploded a hyphen(-) in the resultant array. So if i enter John Chow, i make it John-Chow, which is available in the database. 

Iam also using a plain like search to include more results. So finally my query is: select * from users where name like 'John Chow' UNION select * from users where name like 'John-Chow'

However, iam not using a regular expression based search.